# Not Found - Targeted resource 'PushDevice' does not exist

Tags: push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server

I am currently facing an already known issue: [getting an error on app init() FPWSE0001E: Not Found - Targeted resource 'PushDevice' does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36591845/getting-an-error-on-app-init-fpwse0001e-not-found-targeted-resource-pushde)

related to this APAR: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PI41837

but I am using version 7.0.0.00-20160526-2153 both on my MobileFirst Servers and Studio.

Are there any more fixes related to this error?

> Error 500: DSRA0304E: Unhandled exception caught: FNRCE0001E: Not Found - Targeted resource 'PushDevice' does not exist. Check the '7abbe27c-b207-3f56-82c6-b2315e7f3436' parameter [project NMYACCOUNT]

We followed the steps described in the IBM knowledge center under the section **Deploying a new app version and leaving the old version working**

1. Increment the app version number.
2. Build and test your project and generate new .wlapp, .apk, and .ipa
   files for it.
3. Deploy the new .wlapp files to MobileFirst Server.
4. Submit the new .apk or .ipa files to their respective app stores.
5. Wait for review and approval, and for the apps to become available.

What are your suggestions on approaching this? The app is currently on the production environment and we need to find a workaround asap.

Thanks in advance

Comment: When exactly do you see the error? Is it when trying to dispatch a notification?

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to get the same build, but tried on a later build 7.0.0.0-IF201610071527 , with the following steps :

1. Develop a mobile application that connects to worklight server and enable it for Push Notifications. Let's say the version of the application is 1.0
2. After a successful connection to the worklight server stop the server and close the client application.
3. Update the version number.. .For example from 1.0 to 2.0
4. Deploy the new version of the application on the server and also on the mobile device
5. Start the application on the mobile device.

The device connects successfully to the server, with no exceptions on the server,

so can you try on a later build and let us know, if you are facing the same issue.